# Navbar not collapsing after clicking toggle button. Bootstrap 3 with django

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm experiencing something strange, while trying out bootstrap with django. I copied the dashboard-example from the bootstrap-page ([dashboard-example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)) into my django-project to play around a little bit. When I try to use the collapse navbar for smaller screen-sizes, the navbar is appearing, when I click the toggle-button. But if I click the toggle-button again, the navbar is not disappearing. I copied the example from bootstrap one-to-one. Why is the toggle-button not working as expected? Here is the generated html-code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/static/css/dashboardtest.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/static/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

          <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? To open the console press F12.

Comment: most likely that /static/js/bootstrap.min.js is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

please put bootstrap CDN in that file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```